# Как перевести строку в массив, помогите! PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Я новичок в php, помогите пожалуйста перевести строку такого вида:

```
{"58":2,"55":3,"48":1}
```

в массив

```
array(
  [58] => 2,
  [55] => 3,
  [48] => 1,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r(json_decode('{"58":2,"55":3,"48":1}', true));
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php